# How does one remove BUSINESS labels from Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

I would like to just show the street and public labels (parks, reservoirs, etc.). The labels on/off feature in Google Maps > Earth is all/nothing. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I would [submit a recommendation to Google on this](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/7130583?hl=en&ref_topic=3093612).